# AVPlayer not playing Video file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ipod, avplayer

HI I'm using AVPlayer to play the video slowly frame by frame. I used this coding for that. I could not able to play the video. Please notice my problem.

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 440)];
newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

NSString *videoName = [fileNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSString *url = [Utilities documentsPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OSC/%@/%@.mov",videoName,videoName]];

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
//AVPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]] retain];
AVPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem] retain];
AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer = [[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer] retain];

avPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
[newView.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
[avPlayer play];

avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone; 

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[avPlayer currentItem]];
```

Comment: Sure, Please give some suggestion about my problem please....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about frame by frame slowness, but you're doing a few things you don't need to do. In the iPhone documentation, the Apple guys completely messed with memory management, making it way more complex than it needs to be, so I'll tell you the key things that make it play:

First, retain the player, not the layer. If you don't know why, read a book or the Views Manual. (Which is filled with homonym-style typos, but it's easier than buying a thick book).

2nd, you did not cast the layer and use setPlayer:, the exact line is inside Apple's documentation. You have to convert self.layer using a typecast.

Comment: Forgot to note, the AVPlayer class reference has some interesting typos too, like listing the AspectRatio constants then saying the default is "player", which has nothing to do with the documentation. I'm not reporting it to them 'cause they're jerks about that stuff, but you can still figure it out

Answer (score 11):

Because you use local file, it's better to use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]` for converting NSString to NSURL. So change the code to:

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
```

Comment: This needs to be up voted many many more times.
Using URLWithString will result in silent errors - error == nil, player.status == AVPlayerStatusUnknown.
Switching to fileURLWithPath immediately resolved the non-playing issue.